# Opening Bootstrap accordion scrolls to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I've been trying to figure out why opening accordions on [this page](https://www.parkinson.ca/parkinson-canada-announces-over-1-3-million-in-research-competition-funding/) causes the page to scroll to the top. The accordions are using Bootstrap 3.

I've determined that the code causing it is a click event listener in https://www.parkinson.ca/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/assets/js/site/cs.6f62d0f.js. Removing this listener from Chrome DevTools solves the issue. Somewhere along the way, code is called within this file that causes the page to scroll to the top.

However, I'm trying not to delve into a plugin's code and, instead, prevent that event listener from firing by creating my own event listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", (function(e) {
    var isAccordion = e.target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'collapse';
    if (isAccordion) {
      var accordionHref = e.target.getAttribute('href');
      $(accordionHref).collapse('toggle');
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}));
```

Unfortunately, I found that, immediately after this code is executed, jQuery creates a TransitionEvent since the accordion CSS classes change, which is eventually picked up by the JS file above, causing the scrolling to happen anyway.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The clickable accordion title is an `<a>` tag. When you click on it, it's act like a link. Add `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the callback to stop the execution of the link.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it's not working out. The code is active right now in the <head> of the page.